# Natural isomorphism $\Gamma_\ast(\mathscr{F})^{\tilde{}} \to \mathscr{F}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-verification

This question concerns Proposition 5.15, II, Hartshorne, which states that the natural map $\beta \colon \Gamma_\ast (\mathscr{F})^{\tilde{}} \to \mathscr{F}$ is an isomorphism of $\mathcal{O}_X$ - modules, where $X=\operatorname{Proj} S$ for a graded ring $S$ which is finitely generated by $S_1$ as an $S_0$-algebra, and $\mathscr{F}$ a quasi-coherent sheaf.

The idea to prove this, is to use Lemma 5.14, which I am not going to state here, but I am wondering how exactly one concludes injectivity (and surjectivity) of the map on $D_+(f)$, $f \in S_1$. You don't have to go into the surjectivity since I haven't yet approached it myself.
Here is my approach for the injectivity and I would appreciate it if you could check my reasoning (please be picky).

Let $m/f^d$ be in the kernel of $\Gamma_\ast(\mathscr{F})_{(f)}\to \mathscr{F}(D_+(f))$, i.e. $m_{\vert D_+(f)} \otimes f^{-d}=0$ in $\Gamma(D_+(f), \mathscr{F}(d))\otimes_{S_{(f)}} \Gamma(D_+(f), \mathcal{O}_X(-d))\cong \mathscr{F}(D_+(f))$. This implies that the element $m_{\vert D_+(f)} \otimes f^{-d} \otimes f^d$ is zero in $$\Gamma(D_+(f), \mathscr{F}(d))\otimes_{S_{(f)}} \Gamma(D_+(f), \mathcal{O}_X(-d)) \otimes_{S_{(f)}} \Gamma(D_+(f),\mathcal{O}_X(d)),$$ which is isomorphic to $\Gamma(D_+(f), \mathscr{F}(d))$ (multiplying the entries), whence $m_{\vert D_+(f)} = 0$.
By the lemma, there exists some $n > 0$ such that $f^nm=0$ as a global section of $\mathscr{F}(d) \otimes \mathcal{O}_X(n)\cong \mathscr{F}(n+d)$. But this isomorphism, together with the map $\mathscr{F}(d)(X) \otimes \mathcal{O}_X(n)(X) \to (\mathscr{F}(d) \otimes \mathcal{O}_X(n))(X)$ that comes with the sheafification, is exactly how the scalar multiplication on $\Gamma_\ast(\mathscr{F})$ is defined. So, $m/f^d=0$.

I think what makes this argument work is that $D_+(f)$ is affine since in this case the sections of the tensor product over $D_+(f)$ is just the tensor product of the sections of the individual sheaves over $D_+(f)$ $-$ in case we are talking about quasi-coherent sheaves.

Comment: The argument looks good to me, but I have a question. How do we know that it suffices to check that this morphism of sheaves is an isomorphism in the open sets of the type $D_{+}(f)$ with $f\in S_{1}$? Thank you.